# Azure Data Lake Analytics - Output dates as +0000 rather than -0800

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I have a datetime column in an Azure Data Lake Analytics table.

All my incoming data is UTC +0000. When using the below code, all the csv outputs convert the dates to -0800

```
OUTPUT @data
TO @"/data.csv"
USING Outputters.Text(quoting : false, delimiter : '|');
```

An example datatime in the output:

> 2018-01-15T12:20:13.0000000-08:00

Are there any options for controlling the output format of the dates? I don't really understand why everything is suddenly in -0800 when the incoming data isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, ADLA does not store TimeZone information in DateTime, meaning it will always default to the local time of the cluster machine when reading (-8:00 in your case).  Therefore, you can either normalize your DateTime to this local time by running

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(myDate, DateTimeKind.Local)
```

or use

```
DateTime.ConvertToUtc()
```

to output in Utc form (but note that next time you ingest that same data, ADLA will still default to reading it in offset -0800).  Examples below:

```
@getDates = 
EXTRACT
    id          int,
    date        DateTime
FROM "/test/DateTestUtc.csv"
USING Extractors.Csv();

@formatDates = 
SELECT
    id,
    DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Local) AS localDate,
    date.ConvertToUtc() AS utcDate
FROM @getDates;


OUTPUT @formatDates
TO "/test/dateTestUtcKind_AllUTC.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

You can file a feature request for DateTime with offset on our [ADL feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake).  Let me know if you have other questions!